# x86 assembly from Windows perspective?

Tags: windows, assembly

I'm wanting to learn assembly programming and have found some great resources online, but the majority of them are oriented towards Linux users, DOS users, or use a high level assembler. I have no problem with Linux, but I just prefer Windows. Are there any resources (preferably online, but book is fine) that are oriented towards Windows users. I also would like it to give a strong explanation of the hardware.

Comment: Looking back on my question, I should of been more clear, sorry. I was talking about resources to learn how to program in assembly. I already have an assembler.

Comment: You'll want a good debugger, too; its hard to write assembly code that doesn't need single-stepping to convince yourself it works.

Answer (score 2):

To really learn the Intel/AMD processor, you may want to read from the source:

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals

This will give you everything you need to know about all the instructions. It won't tell you how to write code for your assembler, though. However, Intel uses the same syntax as Microsoft uses, so it should be a perfect match.

Note that AMD has similar books that you can also download. I prefer the Intel docs, but unless you want to use extensions from one of these brands, you'll be good with either one.

These books are free too.

Comment: +1 - These are excellent.  FWIW, back in the good 'ol days (I got mine in 2004), Intel would send you printed and bound book versions of these for FREE if you asked for them (If you want hard copies now, you have to go through a 3rd party print-on-demand service). I guess this was their way of encouraging folks to develop for their CPUs...

Comment: Actually that's Intel's syntax and MS uses it, not the other way around. AT&T created their own syntax and it's common in the Unix/Linux world

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, oops! Thank you for the correction, exactly what I meant to say...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, get a book.

But you'll also want programming tools. Visual Studio Express for C and C++ includes ML, an x86 assembler, and a quite nice development environment.  To my amazement, it is free.  Guess MS is making tons of money on Word.

This suggests you should get a book that is focused on Microsoft assembler, often called "MASM" in spite of being filed under "ML.exe".

Comment: "Get a book" is a very broad statement. Is there any book that you feel is better than others?

Comment: No,  have no opinions.  I learned assembler back in the late 1960s and don't seem to have much need.  You'll discover, if you want to do really interesting things, that having the instruction set reference manuals for the processor (e.g, the Intel or AMD instruction set references) provides lots of dark corner detail on what the machines *really* do.  You can find these at Intel.com and AMD.com pretty easily; they tend to be really huge PDFs.  Disk is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of good info on the web.  http://masm32.com/ for instance.  Also, look up "wininc" (which can be used with jwasm).  Microsoft's own online documentation is a bit challenging to search/read, but has all the details you'll need.

Comment: Unless you are already an expert at assemblers, MS's online documentation is simply opaque.